# How to apply font size attribute to ul marker without afftecting list content's font size

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, script#

I am using a contentEditable div to add my contents. i set the font size, color, face and bullets from my UI using javascript(script#).
I apply my own bullet style using css.
Here is one of my css

```
.marker-check-mark:before{
     content: "\2718";
     margin: 0.5em;
     color : Black; 
}
```

this prints a "check mark" as the "ul" type.

Now i want to give its font size as 16. but i dont want this to affect the font size of the contents of this list.

Is there a way to do this.

One solution is to add font tag or span tag with syle attributes inside every li. But i want to avoid this solution.

please give me a better solution.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're more-or-less answered your own question on this one!

Here's your answer:

```
.marker-check-mark:before{
    content: "\2718";
    margin: 0.5em;
    color : Black;
    font-size: 16px
}
```

The `:before` pseudo-element essentially acts as a stand-alone element in your DOM which means that you can style it entirely separately from the element itself.  So, adding `font-size` to `.marker-check-mark:before` will not effect the font-size of `.marker-check-mark`.

Have a read here for more information on how it all works: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: how can i do the same for Ol list ?

Comment: The CSS in this answer is not element-specific.  If it worked for you on an un-ordered list (UL) then it will work the same for an ordered list (OL).  You need to make sure that it shared the same class name, and I'm assuming that the rest of the CSS you used to target the UL is also generic enough to target OLs.  You can always ask a new question if you need further help from the community.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to set the size of the check marks? Why not simply set the font size of the before selector?

```
.marker-check-mark:before  {
    content:"\2718";
    margin: 0.5em;
    color : Black;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/47Zs9/1/)

Comment: how can i do the same for Ol list ?